# Mocking sockets in java with mockito

Tags: java, sockets, mocking, mockito

I am trying to mock the following call:

```
s.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(serverIPAddress_, serverPort_), 0);
```

so I can test what the rest of the code does when this fails in predictable ways. I use this in my test case:

```
ServerSocketChannel ssc = mock(ServerSocketChannel.class);
when(ServerSocketChannel.open()).thenReturn(ssc);
doNothing().when(ssc.socket().bind(any(), anyInt()));
```

However, the above does not compile with:

```
[javac] /home/yann/projects/flexnbd/src/uk/co/bytemark/flexnbd/FlexNBDTest.java:147: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : method bind(java.lang.Object,int)
[javac] location: class java.net.ServerSocket
[javac]       doNothing().when(ssc.socket().bind(any(), anyInt()));
[javac]                                    ^
[javac] 1 error
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: WOW, this got 1003 views with no upvote or downvote... Isn't there a badge for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ServerSocket` has no bind overload that takes an Object and an int.  It has an overload that takes a `SocketAddress` and an int.  I haven't used Mockito, but I think you may need:

```
doNothing().when(ssc.socket().bind(isA(ServerSocket.class), anyInt()));
```

EDIT: The latest error is because you're trying to pass void to the when method.  The [docs note](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doNothing%28%29), "void methods on mocks do nothing by default.", so you may not need this line at all.

Comment: Sorry, was not clear enough. I know why it is not working, I am unsure how to make it work with mockito's matchers.

Comment: Right, that appear to have solved it.  I just did not need it. Strange behaviour if you ask me but hey, what do I know?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The signatures for `bind` are `bind(java.net.SocketAddress)` or `bind(java.net.SocketAddress,int)`, but you're giving it a `java.lang.Object`.

If you're sure that the runtime type returned by `any()` is a `java.net.SocketAddress`, you can cast it:

```
ssc.socket().bind((SocketAddress)any(), anyInt())
```

(Of course, if it's not you'll get a `ClassCastException`.)

Comment: (I'm not quite sure how Mockito works, but it looks like any() is parametrized, you you've probably got something wrong in the way you use it.)

Comment: Do you use any() via a static import? Perhaps any(SocketAddress.class) would help?

Comment: doNothing().when(ssc.socket().bind((SocketAddress)any(SocketAddress.class), anyInt()));
gives me a 'void' type not allowed here. However, I think this is the right track.